# App crashes when taking photo UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app crashes when I try to take more than one picture using UIMagePickerController. So, first time I take a picture everything is fine, second time around the app crashes without any error messages. I do get this the first time around:

```
2013-01-11 16:36:24.178 DoodleStash[26778:907] Received memory warning.
```

Here's the code I am using to take a photo:

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    self.isNewDoodle = TRUE;
}}
```

And here's what I use to save the photo

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage]) {
    self.doodleImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // Check to make sure the image is new
    if (self.isNewDoodle == TRUE) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.doodleImage, self, @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"confirmUploadSegue" sender:self];
}}
```

Really appreciate any help on this. Complete code is here https://gist.github.com/4515007

Answer (score 0):

First of all for camera open try below lines:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Try this in for save image after camera click:

```
              **UPDATED ANSWER**  

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
        {
           UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        if (self.isNewDoodle == TRUE) 
       {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);}
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"confirmUploadSegue" sender:self];
    }
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
      }

- (void)image:(NSString*)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError*)error contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo
{
    if (error)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Photo Saving Failed"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photo Saved" message:@"Saved To Photo Album"  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Try now this & check.

Comment: Thanks @Vishal. Can you please explain how this will fix the problem or what's different about it?

Comment: Tried the solution above but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a crash, but rather a memory warning (the app is killed by the system in low memory condition). It is hard to tell why your app is using too much memory without seeing all the code. You should use profiler to investigate.

In the code given, you could decrease memory usage by only performing the segue after writing the image (in `image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:`) and zeroing `doodleImage` after it's no longer needed (possibly in `prepareForSegue:sender:`). The latter is particulatrly important if you reuse `TakePhoto` controller (because the second time you use it, you are still holding a reference to previously taken image, effectively doubling memory uage).